# Azure Devops: React App in App Service returning 404

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a React app to an azure app service.  It deploys successfully but every time I got to that app service's url, it returns a 404.

My YAML file:

```
# Node.js with React
# Build a Node.js project that uses React.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '12.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: |
      npm install
    displayName: 'npm install'

  - script: node -r dotenv/config node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --max_old_space_size=4096 build dotenv_config_path=.env.dev
    displayName: "Build react Dev environment"
    timeoutInMinutes: 10  

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: "Copy files to artifact directory"
    inputs:
      Contents: "build/**"
      TargetFolder: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"  

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      ArtifactName: "App-Name"
```

And here is the "Deploy Azure App Service" in the release pipeline:
[image]

The release runs without any errors or issues and is deployed to the app service successfully.  However, when I go to the app service's url, I am getting a 404 error:
[image]

I am really at a loss as to what I am missing here.  I am guessing there is something in the yaml file that needs to be added, but I couldn't find anything in my own research.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was to add a web.config file to the public directory.  I am currently getting another error now which will require more investigation "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"